# Http response Status code

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

What is the best **error status Code** should be sent to Client if dependent server is giving null data.

I believe since its server related error it should come in 5xx but not sure what 5xx can be given.

Comment: check this list http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Comment: I prefer 204 no content

Comment: What do you mean by "null data"?

Comment: Null data should be handled in a different way... not by sending error code

Comment: Please elaborate "if dependent server is giving null data" ? If you did a DB query and the response is NULL (because of not found, at least with MongoDB), consider return 404. At least if the object you were trying to retrieve directly relates to the user HTTP call.

Comment: It depends upon whether this is actually an error or not.  If you're getting an error from the dependent server and that's why you're getting no data, then it is probably a 502 bad gateway.  If you're just getting no data because there is no data that matches the query, then that is likely not an error, but rather a resource not found which could either be a 404 or it could be a successful query (no error at all) with an empty result.  So, it depends upon more context.

Comment: @MikeChamberlain : Null data here means getting null response with 200 OK from dependent server. And since this Node server has to response back to client so asked about what status Code can be considered.

Comment: @SankarRaj: 204 cannot be given since for app http library it will consider it in 2xx so this will not be an error. Moreover no response body can be passed in such case.

Comment: @IanSegers: its not a DB call instead another service call which has to serve data based on request.